Optimizing the Search for a Pythagorean Triplets with a Given $a=16$

Question: Let $16^2+b^2=c^2$ such that  $b,c$  are all Natural numbers.

My Attempt:
We learned in class that a primitive Pythagorean triplet $(a,b,c)$ can be written as $(2st, s^2-t^2, s^2+t^2)$ for some $s,t \in \mathbb{N}$ if $s > t, \gcd(s,t)=1$, and $s+t$ is odd.
So to find pythgaroean triplets where $a=16$, I thought I could find all $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d \mid a$ and for each $d$ we find the corresponding primitive Pythagorean triplet, then multiply all the numbers by $\frac{16}{d}$.
for example, for $d=4$:
$2st=4 \implies st =2 \implies (s,t)=(2,1)$ (because $s > t$ must be fulfilled). And the primitive Pythagorean triplet is $(4,3,5)$, thus our final Pythgaroean triple is $4 \times (4,3,5)=(16, 12, 20)$
I have a hunch that this method is extremely inefficient, so what improvements can be made, or what other methods are there?

Are you looking for $16^2+b^2=c^2$ or $a^2+b^2=16^2$?

I'm looking for $16^2+b^2=c^2$

You mean that $c^2-b^2$, which is in fact $(c-b) \cdot (c+b)$, should be equal to $1 \cdot 256$ (forget it), $2 \cdot 128$, $4 \cdot 64$, $8 \cdot 32$ or $16 \cdot 16$ (the latter being completely useless :-)

To find all positive integers $b$ and $c$ such that $16^2+b^2=c^2$, note that then also
$$16^2=c^2-b^2=(c-b)(c+b),$$
where $16^2=2^8$. It follows that $c-b=2^m$ and $c+b=2^{8-m}$ for some nonnegative integer $m$, so
\begin{eqnarray}
b&=&\frac{2^{8-m}-2^m}{2}=2^{7-m}-2^{m-1},\\
c&=&\frac{2^{8-m}+2^m}{2}=2^{7-m}+2^{m-1}.\\
\end{eqnarray}
Because $b$ is positive we see that $m<4$, and so plugging in $m=1,2,3$ yields the pairs
$$(b,c)=(63,65), (30,34), (12,20).$$

You did not say in the question, but I guess you decided to try only the case
$2st=4$ and not the case $s^2 - t^2 = 4$ because you know that $s^2 - t^2$ must be odd.
This will be the case too for any other factor of $16$. They are all powers of $2$.
Since the only prime factor found in any of these numbers is $2$,
the condition $\gcd(s,t)=1$ tells you what $t$ must be in every case.
Therefore you know what $s$ is.
It seems to me that you can use this to list the possible values of $b$ and $c$ very efficiently. First list all the primitive solutions (each one is basically just plugging the next value of $d$ into the formula $d = 2s$, and the values of $d$ are incredibly easy to enumerate), then scale each solution up by the factor $\frac{16}{2st}$.

Your question suggests you are looking for primitives but your example is not primitive.
For this answer we will use Euclid's formula shown here as
$$A=m^2-k^2\quad B=2mk\quad C=m^2+k^2$$
For any side of a Pythagorean triple, there are $\,2^{n-1}\,$ primitive triples with that matching side where $\,n\,$ is the number of distinct prime factors. For instance, $\,B=60=2^2\cdot3\cdot5\,$ so there are $\,2^{3-1}=4\,$ such triples, et seq:
$$
(11,60,61)\quad
(91,60,109)\quad 
(221,60,229)\quad 
(899,60,901)
$$
For $\,B=16=2^4,\,$ there are $\,2^0=1\,$ matches, i.e.
$\,(63,16,65).\,$
To find matching triples, we solve a Euclid's formula function for $\,k\,$ and test a defined range of $\,m$-values to see if any yield an integer.
$$B=2mk\implies k=\frac{B}{2m}\quad\text{for}\quad \bigg\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{2B+1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor \le m \le \frac{B}{2}$$
The lower limit ensures $m>k$ and the upper limit ensures $k\ge 1.$
$$B=44\implies\\\
 \bigg\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{88+1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor =5 \le m \le \frac{44}{2}=22\\
 \text{ and we find} \quad m\in\{11,22\}\implies k\in\{2,1\}$$
$$F(11,2)=(117,44,125)\quad\quad F(22,1)=(483,44,485)$$
$$\text{For }B=44\implies\\\
 \bigg\lfloor \frac{1+\sqrt{32+1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor =3 \le m \le \frac{16}{2}=8\\ \text{ and we find only} \quad 
m\in\{8\}\implies k\in\{1\}$$
$$F(8,1)=(63,16,65)$$
